# Unable to deploy analytics studio in sfdx

Tags: managed-package, deployment, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I have created a dashboard and dataset in scratch org. and I need to pull the code of analytics studio in sfdx with Vscode.. But unable to pull the code. There is any possible any to pull code in sfdx..
Please help me out, please

I pulled the code and test with a new scratch

AM facing an error while push with a new scratch .as below

[image]

help me out

> The error is - **Fix these sfdcDigest node errors and then upload the file again**

Comment: Probably needing to use the analytics plugins... https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-analytics

Comment: I got a push error while pushing @Phil W

Comment: Looking at the error, it suggests this could be a permissions issue; check permissions for the "Integration User" around the Data Core object.

Comment: You will get more help if instead of just asking for help you let us know what you've tried and where you are stuck. Take a look at [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) for details on how best to ask questions to get the best support from the community. Additionally, it is always a good idea to copy/paste text rather than include screenshots of text since a screenshot isn't usually indexed and made searchable by internet search services.